# Why can't the first pattern in a shell case statement be a multiple pattern?

Tags: shell, posix, standards

The [standard description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) of the `case` statement says:

```
The format for the case construct is as follows:

case word in
  [(]pattern1) compound-list;;
  [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list;;] ...
  [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
esac

The ";;" is optional for the last compound-list.
```

Why can't be `pattern1` be a multiple pattern as well? It seems rather arbitrary, though I'm pretty sure it must not be.

Thanks!

Comment: did you actually try it? (My recollection that in practice there is no restriction). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Given the long history of shell incompatibilities and quirks, "just try it" might be not be the best approach.

Comment: I thought I had tried it without success somewhere... But I can't get an error, even using ash. I guess it's a pure standards question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misinterpreting what they're saying. The grammar on the page you link to does not show such a distinction:

```
case_clause      : Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list    Esac
                 | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list_ns Esac
                 | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak              Esac
                 ;
case_list_ns     : case_list case_item_ns
                 |           case_item_ns
                 ;
case_list        : case_list case_item
                 |           case_item
                 ;
case_item_ns     :     pattern ')'               linebreak
                 |     pattern ')' compound_list linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')'               linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' compound_list linebreak
                 ;
case_item        :     pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
                 |     pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
                 ;
pattern          :             WORD         /* Apply rule 4 */
                 | pattern '|' WORD         /* Do not apply rule 4 */
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in grammars, so maybe *the grammar* (which is the ultimate word, I know) says something different. On the other hand, how would you interpret the text I quoted?

Comment: @ezequiel-garzon, ...I'd interpret that text as less than clear, to be sure -- one clear intent is to indicate that the first pattern is mandatory (while 2..n-1 are optional, and n isn't required to end in `;;`), but you aren't the only person to take the lack of `[ | pattern] ...` as deliberate. That said, we have both the formal grammar and the behavior of shells predating the POSIX standard as guidelines (including both original Bourne and the ksh versions that influenced the standard), and these sources agree to intent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your comment! I must say, almost five years on I had to carefully reread what I had asked!